# Here/Google PositionManager class returns only -1.7976931348623157E308 for both latitude and longitude on android sdk

Tags: java, android, google-api, location

I saw a similar question like this but it it didn't have a proper answer,

```
                    PositioningManager pm = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                    pm.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("longitude is :"+pm.getPosition().getCoordinate().getLongitude());
                    System.out.println("latitude is :"+pm.getPosition().getCoordinate().getLatitude());
                    System.out.println("geocode is :"+pm.getPosition().getCoordinate());
```

I have given both FINE_LOCATION and COARSE_LOCATION permissions but my output for the above code is

```
I/System.out: longitude is :-1.7976931348623157E308
I/System.out: latitude is :-1.7976931348623157E308
I/System.out: geocode is :Lat: -1.7976931348623157E308, Long: -1.7976931348623157E308, Alt: 1.073741824E9
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong?

edit- I changed my datasource to google location services but it still doesnt work

```
    private void initLocationServices(){
    m_googleLocationDataSource = LocationDataSourceGoogleServices.getInstance();

    if (m_googleLocationDataSource != null) {

        PositioningManager pm = PositioningManager.getInstance();
        pm.setDataSource(m_googleLocationDataSource);
        pm.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS);
        userLocation = pm.getPosition().getCoordinate();
        System.out.println("geocode" + userLocation);
        
    }
   }
```

Still returns the same value